# While unwrapping a rope the torque due to tension shouldn't do work as the point of contact does not move while the torque is being applied?

Tags: energy, work, torque, rotation

[image]
This explains my question in more detail

If you don't get what I am asking feel free to comment I would try to improve my question

Comment: try typing answers instead of screenshots. The former are machine searchable, more legible and unambiguous. Use pics for diagrams and images not easily described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right in thinking that work is done by the indicated applied force on the pulley. The torque from the force continuously increases its rotational kinetic energy, an evidence of work being done.

You argue that since the portion of the rope that applied torque during the time $[t,t+dt)$, thus inducing an angular change $d\theta$ in the orientation of the pulley, is no longer in touch with the original point of contact, "hence no work should be done". Fine - post contact no work is done. But what about the work done when it $was$ in contact? It did do work then. It was $dW=\tau d\theta$. Similarly, the next part that follows touches during $(t+dt, t+2dt)$, also similarly does work during its contact. By imagining these sections to be infinitesimally small $(dt\to0)$, you get the continuous case of the rope, applying constant torque and doing work.

On a different note, contact isn't necessary to do work. Imagine, err, non-contact forces.